# Unity 3D - why i dont see error for this simple line of code with Collider2D method

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```cpp
public class move : MonoBehaviour
{
    Animator animator;
    bool dirToRight = true;
    Rigidbody2D rigidbody;
    public float heroSpeed;
    bool onGround;
    public Transform groundTester;
    public float radius;
    public LayerMask layerMask;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();  
        rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();    
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
 
       onGround = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundTester.position, radius, layerMask);
}
}
```

I dont understand why *bool* **"onGround"** field not show *error* message, its bool type not **Collider2d**, the *Physics2D.OverlapCircle()* return **Collider2D** object not bool...... why please explain this magic for me....

Comment: Check [this page](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.html), under "Operators". It has the operator "bool", which I assume is their way of saying that there's an implicit conversion to `bool` defined. The documentation for [`OverlapCircle`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.OverlapCircle.html) says that `null` is returned if there are no colliders in the circle. So I assume that `Collider2D`'s `bool` conversion returns `false` if the `Collider2D` is `null`, and `true` otherwise

Comment: Because the return options of that function either is a collider or an integer. Not a Boolean. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.OverlapCircle.html  You need to add more definition to check if its what you want or not to get bookean

Answer (score 1):

[`Physics2D.OverlapCircle`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.OverlapCircle.html) returns a [`Collider2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.html) which is a [`Behaviour`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Behaviour.html) which is a [`Component`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.html) which is a [`UnityEngine.Object`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.html) which has an [**implicit** `bool` operator](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-operator_Object.html)

> Does the object exist?

it basically return the same as

```
onGround = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundTester.position, radius, layerMask) != null;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe, it's synthetic sugar or shorthand for `if(onGround)` or `if(onGround != null)`.